# Can't see my mobile menu anymore (Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, menu

I have a Wordpress page, which I've set up for a friend. It all worked well, but since a few days or weeks the mobile menu (icon) doesn't show anymore. Can anyone find out what this could be?

The page: http://www.cabane-blanche.ch/

Answer (score 1):

put this code in your theme style.css

```
nav {
    font-size: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A CSS rule in your **themify-customizer.css** file is causing the font size to be 0px for everything inside header.

```
#header {           font-size:0px;

}
```

at **line 59**. You must remove this rule and it will fix this problem. It is also causing the dropdown item at "WARENKORB" tab to not show up.

If you only want to fix the mobile menu leaving the header rule intact, you can add following code to your **style.css**, Although I recommend the fix mentioned above instead.

```
.icon-menu {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```